# How do I install the latest build of xmllint on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: xml, macos, xmllint

The problem is that I am trying to validate an xml file using xmllint. On my machine (OSX 10f.7.5) it says the xml is invalid.  When a co-worker tries it on his machine, it says it is valid.  I am not sure what version of OSX he is running but I do know that my version of xmllint is

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20703
```

and his version is

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20708
```

So the question is how do I build that version (or the latest version) on my machine?

Answer (score 30):

It seems that the xmlstarlet package contains xmllint, so this should do the trick:

```
brew install xmlstarlet
```

I'm not sure how you would get a specific version though.

Answer (score 0):

You can install fink then you can install a deb package from here: http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/libxml2-bin or compile one of the source packages.

You can learn more about fink such as how to install it [Installing fink](http://www.finkproject.org/doc/users-guide/install.php?phpLang=en) and [Installing Packages](http://www.finkproject.org/doc/users-guide/packages.php?phpLang=en)

The name of the package should be libxml12-bin for the package install commands.

One thing to keep in mind is "The project offers precompiled binary packages as well as a fully automated build-from-source system. "  so you can get the latest versions of utilities that are unix/linux/bsd in nature, and if there is no binary build, a few commands can let you build it from source.