# Command Line search all html files, retrieve attribute value

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, find

I need to get all the *inline* "data-title" attribute values out of a bunch of html files that are located in different subdirectories. Is there a simple way to do this on a linux machine?

I had found something similar on another SO post, had attempted editing it, but I am a sed novice:

```
sed "s/.* data-title=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/"
```

I haven't been able to get this part quite right, and I think I'll need an utilize an additional search utility to get this working. Ideally I'd like to get all output to a txt file.

sample:

```
    <aside class="grid-sidebar sidebar">
        <div id="listLoading"><div id="loading-listLoading" class="front-center" style="padding-top: 22%; top: 0%; display: none;"><div style="width: 42px; height: 42px; position: absolute; margin-top: 17px; margin-left: -21px; -webkit-animation: spin12 0.8s linear infinite;"><svg style="width: 42px; height: 42px;"><g transform="translate(21,21)"><g stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="rgb(34, 34, 34)"><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(0, 0, 0)" opacity="1"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(30, 0, 0)" opacity="0.9173553719008265"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(60, 0, 0)" opacity="0.8347107438016529"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(90, 0, 0)" opacity="0.7520661157024794"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(120, 0, 0)" opacity="0.6694214876033058"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(150, 0, 0)" opacity="0.5867768595041323"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(180, 0, 0)" opacity="0.5041322314049588"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(210, 0, 0)" opacity="0.42148760330578516"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(240, 0, 0)" opacity="0.33884297520661155"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(270, 0, 0)" opacity="0.25619834710743805"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(300, 0, 0)" opacity="0.17355371900826455"></line><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="0" y2="18" transform="rotate(330, 0, 0)" opacity="0.09090909090909094"></line></g></g></svg></div></div></div>
        <div id="list" style="position:relative;">
<div style="height: 55px;">
    <h2 class="heading" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Available Records</h2>
</div>
<div style="height: 51px">
            <div class="grid-3-4">
            <label for="searchInput" class="infield" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 55px; display: block;">Search</label>
            <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="searchInput" data-title="title1" title="" style="height: 36px" class="input-long">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-1-4">
    <select id="listStatus" name="status" class="styled input-full hasCustomSelect" data-title="Title 2" title="" style="-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 104px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 36px; font-size: 16px;">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="active" selected="">Active</option>
        <option value="archived">Archived</option>
    </select><span class="customSelect styled input-full" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">Active</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `xmllint` (regex are not the right tool to parse HTML):

```
 $ find . -iname '*.html' -exec xmllint --html --xpath '//node/title' {} \;
```

Or with [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
 $ xmllint --html --xpath '//node/title' **/*.html
```

where node is the name of the node including the title element.

**EDIT**

Nor `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` can parse this HTML properly. A quick working hack is to use:

```
grep -oP 'data-title="\K[^"]+' *files
```

Comment: I know the question was regarding LINUX. Only wanted to add that both xmllint commands fail on OSX.

Comment: What do you mean by fail ? You can install `xmllint`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391717/how-do-i-install-the-latest-build-of-xmllint-on-osx-10-7-5

Comment: I get "Unknown option --xpath" when trying to run these, also, what if all the node names are different?

Comment: You should upgrade `xmllint` or use `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: ok, I've upgraded xmllint, now I get tag errors, guess I should have mentioned it's html5?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you might use (e)grep

`grep -e'<title>.*<\/title>' *.html`

`egrep "<title>.*?<\/title>" *.html`

from within the folder.

Use

`grep -re'<title>.*<\/title>' */*.html`

to parse subdirectories and

`grep -rhe'<title>.*<\/title>' */*.html`

to parse subdirectories and omit the filename display, if you only want the title lines.

Comment: OP says he have many subdirectories, and regex are not designed to parse HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed and pull the title tag data out if you want, if you need to get it from some meta link data then you would have to change it:

```
sed -n 's#.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*#\1#p' *.html
```

If they are on the same line this should do:

```
sed -n "/title=/s/.* title=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p"
```

Otherwise you need to modify it to multiline match (it still can be done with sed).